# Windows 10 Docker MySql:5.6 container not starting when a data volume is mounted

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, windows-10

I need to mount a volume for the database files and I entered following command.

```
docker run -v C:\db\d4:/var/lib/mysql mysql/mysql-server:5.6
```

However it seems that the container is failing to start. I noticed that there are data files have been created in the mounted folder.

I am using Windows 10, Docker 18.09.1, build 4c52b90

This is the output.

```
C:\db>docker run -v C:\db\d4:/var/lib/mysql mysql/mysql-server:5.6
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.6.43-1.1.10
[Entrypoint] No password option specified for new database.
[Entrypoint]   A random onetime password will be generated.
[Entrypoint] Initializing database
2019-02-08 17:05:26 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-02-08 17:05:26 0 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
2019-02-08 17:05:26 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.43) starting as process 20 ...


2019-02-08 17:05:31 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-02-08 17:05:31 0 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
2019-02-08 17:05:31 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.43) starting as process 42 ...




PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !
To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:

  /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
  /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h b6b2a0a64aa6 password 'new-password'

Alternatively you can run:

  /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

which will also give you the option of removing the test
databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
strongly recommended for production servers.

See the manual for more instructions.

Please report any problems at http://bugs.mysql.com/

The latest information about MySQL is available on the web at

  http://www.mysql.com

Support MySQL by buying support/licenses at http://shop.mysql.com

Note: new default config file not created.
Please make sure your config file is current

WARNING: Default config file /etc/my.cnf exists on the system
This file will be read by default by the MySQL server
If you do not want to use this, either remove it, or use the
--defaults-file argument to mysqld_safe when starting the server

[Entrypoint] Database initialized
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
2019-02-08 17:05:33 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-02-08 17:05:33 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.43) starting as process 65 ...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...
[Entrypoint] Timeout during MySQL init.

C:\db>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

C:\db>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

C:\db>
```

Can someone help me narrow down the issue here.

Comment: What is the status of ```docker ps -a```?

You can also do this: ```docker logs image_name``` see what is in there!

However, I guess it is because you didn't set a password!

Comment: Hi Aaron, even if I set the password, same result. `ps -a` will show the exited container.

Comment: Did you check out this? https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

They have pretty good documentation on how to create/start and use their images.

Comment: Yes Aaron. However, same works on CentOS and Ubuntu. I have a requirement to run this on Windows. I tried creating a Ubuntu VM and sharing host folder to vm and tried docker still fails.